# Get the most popular value from an array using array methods

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects

```js
const doggos = [
  { name: 'Scruffy', breed: 'Labrador', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Charlie', breed: 'Poodle', age: 8, trained: true },
  { name: 'Shandy', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 2, trained: false },
  { name: 'Mossy', breed: 'Border Collie', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Winston', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 12, trained: false },
  { name: 'Humphrey', breed: 'Jack Russel', age: 5, trained: true },
  { name: 'Spike', breed: 'Boxer', age: 10, trained: true },
  { name: 'Hunter', breed: 'German Pointer', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Marlo', breed: 'Labrador', age: 4, trained: false },
  { name: 'Dave', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 7, trained: true }
];
```

I want to display the most popular breed of dog. 
How would I do this using .map .filter .sort or any other array method?

My aim is to simply improve my javascript

Comment: What's the definition of "most popular"? Is it the older the better? or whether its trained?

Comment: @Isaac Most frequent I guess.

Comment: Yes I mean most frequent. In this example the answer would be 'Bulldog'

Comment: I don't think you have count the occurrence using just map, filter and sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.reduce()` to create a `Map` with which uses each `breed` as a key and a value as the number of occurrences seen so far. For each dog in `doggos`, you can check if the breed currently exists in the map, if it doesn't, add the breed as a key and set its associated occurrence value to 1, if it does already exist you can add to the current occurrence value. To get the max you can use `Math.max()` and then `.find()` to get entry which has the max as its occurrence value:

```js
const doggos = [ { name: 'Scruffy', breed: 'Labrador', age: 3, trained: true }, { name: 'Charlie', breed: 'Poodle', age: 8, trained: true }, { name: 'Shandy', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 2, trained: false }, { name: 'Mossy', breed: 'Border Collie', age: 3, trained: true }, { name: 'Winston', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 12, trained: false }, { name: 'Humphrey', breed: 'Jack Russel', age: 5, trained: true }, { name: 'Spike', breed: 'Boxer', age: 10, trained: true }, { name: 'Hunter', breed: 'German Pointer', age: 3, trained: true }, { name: 'Marlo', breed: 'Labrador', age: 4, trained: false }, { name: 'Dave', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 7, trained: true } ];

const entries = [...doggos.reduce((m, {breed}) => m.set(breed, (m.get(breed) || 0)+1) , new Map)];
const max = Math.max(...entries.map(([_, amt]) => amt));
const [most_popular] = entries.find(([_, amt]) => amt === max);
console.log(most_popular);
```

Alternatively, a slightly more efficient approach would be to perform the Math.max() logic yourself by again using `.reduce()` on your entries array:

```js
const doggos = [ { name: 'Scruffy', breed: 'Labrador', age: 3, trained: true }, { name: 'Charlie', breed: 'Poodle', age: 8, trained: true }, { name: 'Shandy', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 2, trained: false }, { name: 'Mossy', breed: 'Border Collie', age: 3, trained: true }, { name: 'Winston', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 12, trained: false }, { name: 'Humphrey', breed: 'Jack Russel', age: 5, trained: true }, { name: 'Spike', breed: 'Boxer', age: 10, trained: true }, { name: 'Hunter', breed: 'German Pointer', age: 3, trained: true }, { name: 'Marlo', breed: 'Labrador', age: 4, trained: false }, { name: 'Dave', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 7, trained: true } ];

const entries = [...doggos.reduce((m, {breed}) => m.set(breed, (m.get(breed) || 0)+1) , new Map)];
const [most_popular] = entries.reduce(([old,max], [breed, amt]) => amt > max ? [breed, amt] : [old, max]);
console.log(most_popular);
```

Comment: Opps I thought OP wanted to have the result of Bulldogs in an array haha..

Comment: @Isaac you might be correct, not exactly sure what the output should look like

Answer (score 0):

```js
const doggos = [
  { name: 'Scruffy', breed: 'Labrador', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Charlie', breed: 'Poodle', age: 8, trained: true },
  { name: 'Shandy', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 2, trained: false },
  { name: 'Mossy', breed: 'Border Collie', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Winston', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 12, trained: false },
  { name: 'Humphrey', breed: 'Jack Russel', age: 5, trained: true },
  { name: 'Spike', breed: 'Boxer', age: 10, trained: true },
  { name: 'Hunter', breed: 'German Pointer', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Marlo', breed: 'Labrador', age: 4, trained: false },
  { name: 'Dave', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 7, trained: true }
];

let finalObj = {};
doggos.forEach(dog => {
  let breedCount = finalObj[dog.breed] || 0;
  breedCount += 1;
  
  finalObj[dog.breed] = breedCount;
});

const maxBreed = Object.entries(finalObj).reduce((final, current) => {
  if(current[1] > final[1]) return current;
  return final;
});

const resultDoggos = doggos.filter(dog => dog.breed === maxBreed[0]);

console.log(resultDoggos)
```

Breaking it into multiple parts. First part trying to using `forEach` to transform the array into object, with the count for each breed.

Second step then from the object finding the single breed with greatest count.

Third step then filter the original array with the breed.

The above answer covers the usage of `forEach`, `Object.entries.reduce`, `Array.filter`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const doggos = [
  { name: 'Scruffy', breed: 'Labrador', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Charlie', breed: 'Poodle', age: 8, trained: true },
  { name: 'Shandy', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 2, trained: false },
  { name: 'Mossy', breed: 'Border Collie', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Winston', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 12, trained: false },
  { name: 'Humphrey', breed: 'Jack Russel', age: 5, trained: true },
  { name: 'Spike', breed: 'Boxer', age: 10, trained: true },
  { name: 'Hunter', breed: 'German Pointer', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Marlo', breed: 'Labrador', age: 4, trained: false },
  { name: 'Dave', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 7, trained: true }
];

const result = Object.entries(doggos.map(e => e.breed).reduce((acc, e) => acc[e] ? {...acc, [e]: acc[e]+1} : {...acc, [e]: 1}, {})).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0];
console.log(`Breed: ${result[0]}, Count: ${result[1]}`);
```

You can replace the last `sort` by `reduce`. This will reduce some time complexity.

```js
const doggos = [
  { name: 'Scruffy', breed: 'Labrador', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Charlie', breed: 'Poodle', age: 8, trained: true },
  { name: 'Shandy', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 2, trained: false },
  { name: 'Mossy', breed: 'Border Collie', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Winston', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 12, trained: false },
  { name: 'Humphrey', breed: 'Jack Russel', age: 5, trained: true },
  { name: 'Spike', breed: 'Boxer', age: 10, trained: true },
  { name: 'Hunter', breed: 'German Pointer', age: 3, trained: true },
  { name: 'Marlo', breed: 'Labrador', age: 4, trained: false },
  { name: 'Dave', breed: 'Bulldog', age: 7, trained: true }
];

const result = Object.entries(doggos.map(e => e.breed).reduce((acc, e) => acc[e] ? {...acc, [e]: acc[e]+1} : {...acc, [e]: 1}, {})).reduce((acc, e) => acc[1] > e[1] ? acc : e);
console.log(`Breed: ${result[0]}, Count: ${result[1]}`);
```

You can use `doggos.filter(e => e.breed == result[0])` at the end to extract all the dogs of the most frequent breed.